# What color is the text in the detail view of a UITableViewCellStyleValue1?

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

I've added a text field in one of the accessory views of my table view. The problem is that the color of the text is black, and the color in the detail views of the other cells around it are some kind of lightish blue. I want the text in the text field to have the same color and it's not `[UIColor blueColor];`

So does anyone know how I can get the color in my text field to have the same color as the cells around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably to read out the color from the `detailTextLabel`'s `textColor` property. Or set the `textColor` on the `detailTextLabel` on all the other cells when you create them. That way they will all remain the same even if Apple changes the color (or introduces theming of some sort) in a future version of the OS.

On the 4.2 simulator, the color seems to be `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0]`.